# unable to connect via rdp to a google cloud windows server vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rdp, windows-server

I have one instance of a Windows Server 12 R2 VM on google cloud that's working properly and I have connected to it successfully using RDP. I have tried to replicate it by creating a snapshot out of it and creating an instance from the snapshot. According to the platform the instance was created, but i can't seem to connect to it or to get a password. When I click "Get windows password" I get this:
[image]

forever. When i try to connect to it, I get
[image]

I have no idea what to do, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue where in the popup would not close at all. It was issue with Firefox. The same worked in google chrome.

Comment: I dont know, I have deleted that server and created a new one. It didnt happen since, and I've stopped replicating servers because I'm using active directory, so it will probably not happen again. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The password creation tool from the console only works for images builted from the official image repo. In this case your source is a previous VM through a snapshot. In that case, and also in migrations all the previous credentials are kept in the new VM. You can download the GCP RDP agent [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-rdp-for-google-clo/mpbbnannobiobpnfblimoapbephgifkm/) and access using the credential you used to have in your source VM.

Connecting to a Windows Instance
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/connecting-to-windows-instance

-----------Update----------------

In the case you can not get to enter the VM, it seems to be a firewall rules issue. By default the port tcp:3389(RDP access) is open to all VM at the default network, check your VM is in that network or check if the firewall rule has a tag to be applied.

If not, apply a tag to your new machine and create a firewall rule tobe applied to that tag.

Hope it help. Keep  us posted!

Comment: That could be true, although my past experience is different. I have, in a different account, created a new password for a replicated instance. The thing is, as long as i cant find the server with RDP, it doesnt matter. I dont get to the point where I can try to put in credentials, it as if the server is off or doesn't exist